# Is it possible to apply RGBA border in IE6/7/8?

Tags: css

My CSS looks like this:

```
#bbb {
  border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .45) 200px;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 960px;
}
```

I really need to make the border transparent, but it doesn't work on IE6/7/8, how do I deal with it ?

Comment: [Can I use CSS3 Colors](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba)

Comment: I'm quite sure it's a *XY* question, why do you need a so big border?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without using images would be:

**HTML**

```
<div class="component">
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class="content">..Content..</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
   div.component {
    position: relative;
}
div.background {
    background:#f00;
    position: absolute;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-opacity: 0.5;
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
}
div.content {
    background:#fff;
}
```

you can scale the border as big as you want. This one uses positioning, you could use padding/margin as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7Srh/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead, it's basically rendering a "border `div`" with a transparent background around a "content `div`". The "border width" is set by changing the `padding` value in `div.border`, and the colour/transparency is coming from the `background-image` value, which currently links to a `50% transparent black` pixel sized image .

**HTML**

```
<div class="border">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.content {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}
div.border {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    padding: 200px;
    background-image: url(https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6928212/halftransparentpixel.gif);
    zoom: 1;
}
```

Here's a <kbd>[**fullscreen jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UQ9U6/2/embedded/result/)</kbd> which should work in IE6/7/8.

And here's the link to the <kbd>[**editable jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UQ9U6/2)</kbd> which won't load properly in older browsers.

Comment: IE6 and IE7 have problems with transparent PNG images [link](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6/)

Comment: @FezVrasta - Thanks, I've fixed the post and fiddles up with a GIF image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use RGBA in IE8 and older, and as far as I know there's no polyfill for it either.

As others have said already you could use a background instead, but you don't need to use an image. You also cannot use `Opactiy` (or `filter: alpha(opacity)`) since this also makes the children transparent.

Instead, you can assign the parent element a single color `filter` gradient in ARGB format.

```
.parent {
  background: transparent;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */
  zoom: 1;
}
```

This is the equivalent to `background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);` in modern browsers.

For a longer explaination and a rgba to argb converter, see [this article](http://kimili.com/JOURNAL/RGBA-HSLA-CSS-GENERATOR-FOR-INTERNET-EXPLORER).